# Plot "Y-Less" Date Only Chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is challenging me. I've trying to plot a chart based on DataFrame:

```
BaseDate    EventDate           EventType
11/6/2009   11/6/2009 9:00      S
11/6/2009   11/6/2009 17:00     E
11/9/2009   11/9/2009 10:00     S
11/9/2009   11/9/2009 14:00     E
11/10/2009  11/10/2009 11:00    S
11/10/2009  11/10/2009 18:00    E
11/11/2009  11/11/2009 9:00     S
11/11/2009  11/11/2009 10:00    E
11/12/2009  11/12/2009 7:00     S
11/12/2009  11/12/2009 20:00    E
```

The plot itself is very simple: I want to draw a vertical line for every EventTime and colored by EventType. Of course, the most obvious call doesn't work: `ggplot(logdates, aes(x = EventDate, y = EventType, color = EventType)) + geom_bar()`.

Do you have any idea on how to create this chart?

**UPDATE**:

as requested, here is a draft of what I'm trying to do. Note that there is no Y axis, as I don't have any value for it.

[image: Draft of a chart]

Thanks!

Comment: I'll upload a sample graph and fix the wrong column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure everything is defined correctly:

```
df$EventTime <- as.POSIXct(df$EventTime, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', tz="UTC")
df$EventType <- as.factor(df$EventType)
```

Not sure if that's close to what you want, but at least it has some vertical lines:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=EventTime, 
               ymin=0, 
               ymax=1, 
               colour=EventType)) +
  geom_linerange() + 
  theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: This is almost there! The only difference is that I would like to have them at the same height, as the draft I just uploaded. Seems that removing the +/- 1/4 broke the chart...

Comment: @shadow I was very confused by that at first, but in fact "Nov 07" is not "November 2007", but "November the 7th (of 2009)".

Comment: @RafaBorges In my picture they have equal height, don't they?

Comment: The first version you uploaded had different heights for different types. But it doesn't matter, as now they do and it is working flawless!